# Notepad++ checking and removing duplicates in 2 documents at time

Tags: duplicates, notepad++

If someone can please tell me if there is a way to check for duplicates on 2 different opened documents on the same time, I would really appreciate it.

I will explain what i exactly need and why i need this sorted out.

I have 2 documents with two different lists of names that i need to use on my daily business.
Everyday i receive a new list of names; those might vary from 50 to 200, to even 500 per day.
In some circumstances, certain names on document A must be removed and placed on document B. If this occurs, the names on document A cannot be duplicates on document B and vice versa.
The names i receive daily also cannot be duplicates on either Document A or Document B.

Other than checking the names manually with the string "Find", until now i had no way to do this and is a very tedious and long process, is taking me hours and sometimes it happens that i skip some duplicates or i miss names on list A that are on list B and this is not ok.

Is there a way to have a tool that can help me do this in a easier and faster way?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Yes, there is a tool called a database, which is properly equipped to handle the sort of problem you are facing.  Besides being error prone, using hand maintained text files is, as you have seen, tedious.  If you plan on having this need for much longer, investing in a database could have a hefty payoff later on.

Comment: Yes i do need this for long term. Can you explain how this database works and how i can get it?
Thanks

Comment: If you want a fairly flexible, free, database, then MySQL is one option.  You can download it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).  Note you are about to hit a learning curve.

Comment: I was using MySQL for my website, but this was several years ago. Never thought i would need this for such a simple task as checking duplicates.
Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Sure you can handle this with Excel, Perl, Java, a number of tools.  But you said you receive a list of names every day.  It seems that a DB would be a safe and appropriate option.

Comment: Yes, like for today i got 250 names and it hurts my arm on doing this manually...really!
I will give a shot and see if i'm able to manage MySQL.

Comment: If you had both sets of names in separate tables this would be a 30 second problem.

Comment: So, i've spent my entire day installing MySQL, trying to import my text files into tables (which btw was a hassle as Notepad++ does not save my plain text file that does not contains coma's, nor other kind of punctuation in .csv and there was no way to import the names on the tables in another way), I tried to figure how to remove the already existing duplicates as the lists i have does already contains duplicates...
To make it short: there isn't really an easier way to do this? Because i lost an entire day of work with the DB for nothing.